# reflash Asus G752VS BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi, asus-laptop, firmware

after adding custom secure boot keys to my brand-new Asus G752VS from within the BIOS, it won't POST anymore (powers up, but screen is blank and unresponsive). i suspect the BIOS has corrupted its own firmware.

are there any options to reflash the BIOS firmware on my own, given that i cannot access the BIOS to use its built-in functionality? it's under warranty, but Asus quoted me upwards of $400 for something ultimately caused by a severe software defect (BIOS shouldn't be able to corrupt itself like that).

i'm not above opening it carefully to work with its innards, but i'm concerned this may be more complicated than the old "short the CMOS contacts" technique.

Comment: If it won't POST and without specialized hardware your limited to allowing someone who does has the knowledge and hardware to do it for you

Comment: I have never heard of a BIOS which supports Boot keys. Are you sure it is not UEFI ?(Short CMOS would work with BIOS, but possibly not with [U] EFI).

Comment: @Hennes: yes, it's UEFI. sorry if the reference to CMOS was confusing — i meant to contrast with legacy BIOSes that can be easily reset by shorting them out. i'm assuming this would not be so simple — however i'm a hobbyist of sorts, and willing to learn :)

Comment: No worries. It was more intended as a pointer that EFI firmware stores information on the E|FI boot partition and that the old motherboards with BIOS firmware and reset CMOS trick might not work here.

Comment: I guess "CMOS" is close enough – the UEFI variables (including Secure Boot parameters) are still stored in the same kind of NVRAM memory, aren't they... Some motherboards should have a way of wiping it.